# php 7.1 intval behaving weird?

Tags: php

i am doing some calculation where i noticed intval weird behavior

which is making a whole lot of mess because i just want int part of whole variable but intval is stabbing me in the back in comparisons. Any ideas why its behaving like that and what i can use for my requirement?

```
 intval( 9.62 * 100 ) //gives 961
    (int)( 9.62 * 100 )  // gives 962.0
```

my tried methods to achieve my goals were:

```
floor(9.62 * 100)  // but its giving 962.0 no acceptable
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: i like to have out 962 only without decimal part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
intval(strval( 9.62 * 100));
```

It seems to be a problem with the precision of floating points, and converting the number to string and then to int seems to fix the problem.

Here is a link to the documentation, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

As it states,

> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like 7.9999999999999991118....

```
 echo intval((0.1 + 0.7) * 10); //returns 7
 echo intval(strval(0.1 + 0.7) * 10); //returns 8
```

Comment: Thanks, mean basically need to convert var into string to get right result from intval.

Comment: yes, this only happens when the number is type double.

Comment: @kshitij I have updated my answer with some more details.

Answer (score 1):

Since `(int)` always rounds the number down, a small error in the representation makes the cast round it one number down that you would otherwise expect.

I tried `sprintf('%.40F', 9.62 * 100.0);`, and get this: `"961.9999999999998863131622783839702606201172"`.

Thats why `intval( 9.62 * 100 )` gives you `961`.

You can try to use `bcmul()`

```
(int) bcmul(9.62, 100);
```

Comment: As long as the `bcmath` extension is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

> ceil(9.62*100);

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks